# get number of lines of a paragraph having been appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

When executing the code below(on jsfiddle) for the first time, it alerts 2,2,3,2,5,9 in a sequential order.
however, executions after the first one always shows 2,2,3,2,6,9. (5 -> 6)

The right value is 6, as seen from a fifth paragraph in a red div on jsfiddle.

(this happens on chrome / safari on mac)

I assume the problem is it's not waiting for the construction of DOM of the appended element.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$(function(){
    let eachPara = $("div:eq(0)").html().split("</p>");
    let lineHeight = 18;


    $("div:eq(0) p").each(function(i, val) {


        $("#parent").append($(this).clone());


        let eachRowN = $("#parent p:eq(-1)").height() / lineHeight;


        alert(eachRowN);
  });

});
```

complete code:
https://jsfiddle.net/fptd4xkh/1/

```js
$(function() {
  let eachPara = $("div:eq(0)").html().split("</p>");
  let lineHeight = 18;
  $("div:eq(0) p").each(function(i, val) {
    $("#parent").append($(this).clone());
    let eachRowN = $("#parent p:eq(-1)").height() / lineHeight;
    console.log(Math.round(eachRowN));
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 430px;
  background-color: red;
}

#parent p {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 17px;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-indent: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
  /* 両端揃え(均等割り付け) */
  font-family: "Vesper Libre", serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>"Christmas won't be Christmas without any presents," grumbled Jo, lying on the rug.</p>
  <p>"It's so dreadful to be poor!" sighed Meg, looking down at her old dress.</p>
  <p>"I don't think it's fair for some girls to have plenty of pretty things, and other girls nothing at all," added little Amy, with an injured sniff.</p>
  <p>"We've got Father and Mother, and each other," said Beth contentedly from her corner.</p>
  <p>The four young faces on which the firelight shone brightened at the cheerful words, but darkened again as Jo said sadly, "We haven't got Father, and shall not have him for a long time." She didn't say "perhaps never," but each silently added it, thinking
    of Father far away, where the fighting was.</p>
  <p>Nobody spoke for a minute; then Meg said in an altered tone, "You know the reason Mother proposed not having any presents this Christmas was because it is going to be a hard winter for everyone; and she thinks we ought not to spend money for pleasure,
    when our men are suffering so in the army. We can't do much, but we can make our little sacrifices, and ought to do it gladly. But I am afraid I don't," and Meg shook her head, as she thought regretfully of all the pretty things she wanted.</p>
</div>

<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Adding the google-font as an resource to the js-fiddle fixes it for me. Gives 6, on the first execution.

Comment: I think I've already added google font properly on body tag.

Comment: You think? In Jsfiddle there is in the left column a resource tab. You should always add all your resources there (doing different will result in strange load behavoir like fonts loading after dom-ready gets triggered).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I set it on the left column, but still get the same result.

Comment: Goodluck. As I said before, adding the google font as a resource fixed the first execution and gives an 6 as answer.

Comment: Forked the fiddle and added the required resources, hopefully this helps? The [link](https://jsfiddle.net/peterbode1989/ucsvr3m6/)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Did some testing and it just went from working to not working.. let me do some research (stopped working after I saved..)..

Comment: Found the problem. The font-family only applies to the #parent element. And not the element where they are cloned from. If I give all the elements the required font-face, this result in 6 lines being counted I updated the previous fiddle.

Comment: @PeterBode No need to add jquery. Already added by the settings to the JS pane

Comment: @mplungjan yeah saw that afterwards. The add was more to check too exclude a jQuery version problem or something..

Comment: Thank you, sir. This solved the problem.

Comment: Removed jQuery as resource from the Fiddle, and turned the console.log into an alert like OP did.

Comment: Good to hear, goodluck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spot from where you calculate doesn't have the correct font-face. Try the following.

Change:

```
#parent {
    width: 430px;
    background-color: red;
}

#parent p {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 17px;
    hyphens: auto;
    text-indent: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "Vesper Libre", serif;
}
```

Into:

```
div {
    font-family: "Vesper Libre", serif;
}

#parent {
    width: 430px;
    background-color: red;
}

#parent p {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 17px;
    hyphens: auto;
    text-indent: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
}
```